# Database Design for sub columns or many to many relations

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, rdbms

If I have a list of theatres and in each theatre there are several classes of tickets eg. Rs.120, Rs.100 etc. These classes will apply for morning, noon and night shows.  So all the classes of tickets will be available for all the shows(Many to Many Relationship)  I need to model this as a database.  I have a problem in modelling the classes and show timings.  This makes the data base redundant.

[Input Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW7u3.png)

Comment: No images please, post the table structures and data as text in your question

Comment: A start might be three tables: theatres, tickets, and a junction table relating theatres to tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good rule of thumb, is when you hit redundant data, make a new table.
Here is how I would break it down, though you could break it down further (also see a term normalize):

Tables:
theater_tbl
ticket_tbl
classes_tbl

relate each ticket to a class, and each theater may sell one or more tickets of any given class.

Information like address of theater go with theater_tbl
Ticket pricing would go in the ticket table under the type of ticket, unless I misunderstand what a class of ticket is, then the pricing should go there.
The time of day a ticket relates to should go in the ticket table.

This should get you started. To go further, you could break down show times into another table, and relate classes/tickets to those show times.

Its hard to draw out without a solid example.